# Automated backup over FTPS? What is the best software to achieve this?

Tags: windows, backup, ftps

I'm looking for a relatively easy to set up / maintain solution for backup to a remote location over FTPS on a Windows OS.

We currently use Mozy, but would like a second backup to a server on our premises (the server to be backed up is remote). We would also like to be able to configure automation of this process.

Assuming that I've set up FileZilla server with a security certificate etc, is there a good client that anyone can recommend that can connect via FTPS and automate the transfer of files on a schedule?

Comment: What operating system(s)?

Comment: SFTP? FileZilla's server doesn't support SCP?

Comment: Windows is the OS (Original post edited)

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: He probably means FTPS.  Or else has setup FileZilla Server for FTPS, thinking that is the same as SFTP that they use elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like I do mean FTPS as opposed to SFTP. Sorry, bit new to this, didn't realise the distinction! (Post edited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found a solution. Hope this is of use to others. Settled on http://www.scriptftp.com/, seems to do everything I need. Trying for 30 days, not yet licenced.

Automation over FTPS is achieved with the following script in conjunction with the program.

I'm open to suggestions still of other clients if anyone has any experience, so won't close this question for a while...

```
#
# More script samples at http://www.ScriptFTP.com/examples.php
# Online scripting guide at http://www.ScriptFTP.com/reference.php
# Free technical support at http://www.ScriptFTP.com/contact.php
#
# Remember to save the changes before clicking run on the ScriptFTP window.

# Set protocol to FTPS, encryping username, password and data
SETPROTOCOL(FTPS_EXPLICIT_ENCRYPT_DATA)

# Connect to FTP server
OPENHOST("62.XXX.XXX.XX","user","myPassWd")

# Send all the files and subdirectories in C:\MyDir to the server
PUTFILE("C:\FTP_ROOT\*.*",SUBDIRS)

# Transfer finished, close the connection
CLOSEHOST
```

Answer (score 1):

We've been using http://www.ipswitchft.com/products/moveitFreely/index.aspx for the last couple of years without any problems.

eg.

`FTPS.exe -a -s:ftpscript.scr xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx>xferlog.log`

`# ftpscript.scr

username

password

cd ftp_root

put *.*

quit`